# US Pre-1987 Visa Issue Data?

Tags: united-states, immigration, reference-request, visa

I can see a count of nonimmigrant visas issued by classification on the Dept. of State Bureau of Consular Affairs [website](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/visa-law0/visa-statistics/nonimmigrant-visa-statistics.html) going back as far as 1987, but the H-1 visa [was established in 1952](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-1B_visa#Creation).

Does anyone know where I can get counts of visas issued prior to 1987? Any visa data is appreciated, but nonimmigrant visas and H-1 visa data in particular is of greatest interest to me.

Feel free to let me know if there is a better SE site for this sort of policy research question.

Comment: Based on this tweet it seems the state department is confirming data prior to 1987 is unavailable...but I'm not sure if this counts as authoritative https://twitter.com/TravelGov/status/1243985245382283266